# Add equation number in array

Tags: equations, numbering, arrays

I'm struggling with aligning my equations and provide a number for them. I googled but haven't found a solution for the array environment. 
I tried the `align` env. but only with the `array` env. I managed to get the result I was looking for. 
Now I want to label the two conversation equations at the end of the line (preferably vertically centered).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lrcl}
\textbf{Conservation of energy}     & E_{kin}               &=& E'_{kin}                \\
                & m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2         &=& m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \\
                & m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)        &=& m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)      \\
                & m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)     &=& m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)   \\
\\

\textbf{Conservation of momentum}   & p                 &=& p' \\
                & m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2             &=& m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2\\
                & m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)            &=& m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

To make it clearer: I want the black number to be gone and the red numbers to appear:

[image: Screenshot with added numbers]

Comment: No \begin{equation} ? It seems there are many problems in the posted code

Comment: Whoops, that went missing when I edited it here. 
What other problems do you see?

Comment: It is ok now. I had some problems for compiling. Now it is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: the `array` environment is for arrays and matrices etc, it is not at all designed for typesetting full equations, the spacing is wrong for that and the entries are in textstyle not displaystyle which is why your images look so cramped. You should use `align` or `aligned` from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Thanks. As I've said I didn't get the desired result with align. However, gernot showed me a way to use it.

Comment: `align` is designed to number each row, it is better to use `split` or `aligned` or `gathered` which are designed to number the equation as a whole.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

amsmath has several environments designed to number each row, or as here number the group as a whole. Do not use `array` for such display constructs the spacing and style are not designed for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}

\textbf{Conservation of energy}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  E_{\mathrm{kin}}                  &= E'_{\mathrm{kin}}                   \\
  m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2             &= m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \\
  m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)            &= m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)              \\
  m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1) &= m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2) 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\textbf{Conservation of momentum}  
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  p                  &= p'                      \\
  m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2  &= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2 \\
  m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1) &= m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Comment: @infinitezero Oh! Aligning bot parts on the `=`'s was unnecessary? If I only know...

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke do what feels right not what the OP asks for:-)

Comment: Yeah it was necessary but this solution covers it.

Comment: @infinitezero just updated with fixed markup for `kin` (never use math italic for words, it is designed to make consecutive letters look like a product of variables, not a word)

Comment: @infinitezero David Carlisle's solution is nice, but aligning is an optic illusion. If you add something to `= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2\\`, you will see it.

Comment: @infinitezero here the = in each block are aligned but each block is centred so there is no actual alignment between the first and second `equation` environments, but there is no reason to have alignment there so that's OK:-)

Answer (score 3):

You could do it this way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  & \textbf{Conservation of energy} 
   & E_{kin}                          &= E'_{kin}                         \notag\\
  && m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2            &= m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2}    \\
  && m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)           &= m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)           \notag\\
  && m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)&= m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)\notag\\[2ex]
  & \textbf{Conservation of momentum}
   & p                                &= p'                               \notag\\
  && m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2                &= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2                \\
  && m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)               &= m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)               \notag
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is almost perfect! Now if there was a way to get the (1) between the 2nd and 3rd line, it'd be the icing on the cake. :)

Comment: Remove an equation to get an odd number of lines. Form before content. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `alignedat`, but some manual work is needed for sharing the column widths across the two parts; we identify the widest columns in the global alignment and set three dimensions before doing the display.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newlength{\izA}\newlength{\izB}\newlength{\izC}
\newcommand{\mmb}[3]{\mathmakebox[#1][#2]{\displaystyle#3}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
%%% settings for the display
\settowidth{\izA}{\textbf{Conservation of momentum}}%
\settowidth{\izB}{$\displaystyle m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)$}%
\settowidth{\izC}{$\displaystyle m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)$}%
%%%
\begin{gather}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\mmb{\izA}{l}{\textbf{Conservation of energy}}
   & \mmb{\izB}{r}{E_{\mathrm{kin}}}   &= \mmb{\izC}{l}{E'_{\mathrm{kin}}}    \\
  && m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2             &= m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \\
  && m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)            &= m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)              \\
  && m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1) &= m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)
\end{alignedat}
\\
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&\textbf{Conservation of momentum}
   & \mmb{\izB}{r}{p}                  &= \mmb{\izC}{l}{p'}                   \\
  && m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2                 &= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2             \\
  && m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)                &= m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternative solution with `split`, so we need less measuring.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,amssymb,amsthm}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\newlength{\lefthandside}
\newcommand{\leftbox}[2][]{%
  \makebox[\lefthandside][s]{#1\hfill$\displaystyle#2$}%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[2]
%%% settings for the display
\settowidth{\lefthandside}{%
  \textbf{Conservation of momentum}%
  \quad
  $\displaystyle m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)$%
}%
%%%
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
\leftbox[\textbf{Conservation of energy}]
  {E_{\mathrm{kin}}}                        &= E'_{\mathrm{kin}} \\
\leftbox{m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2}             &= m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \\
\leftbox{m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)}            &= m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)              \\
\leftbox{m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)} &= m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)
\end{split}
\\
\begin{split}
\leftbox[\textbf{Conservation of momentum}]
  {p}                                       &= p'                   \\
\leftbox{m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2}                 &= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2             \\
\leftbox{m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)}                &= m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)
\end{split}
\end{align}
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If some manual work is allowed, the following solution gives the desired effect:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}


\newlength{\comom} 
\settowidth{\comom}{\textbf{Conservation of momentum}}
\newlength{\rfour}
\settowidth{\rfour}{$m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)   $}
\begin{eqnarray}
%\begin{array}{lrcl}
\begin{array}{p{\comom}rcl}
\textbf{Conservation of energy}     & E_{kin}               &=& E'_{kin}                \\
                & m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2         &=& m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \\
                & m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)        &=& m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)      \\
                & m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)     &=& m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)   
 \end{array}               
\\
\begin{array}{p{\comom}rcl}
\textbf{Conservation of momentum}   & \makebox[\rfour][r]{$p               $}  &=& \makebox[\rfour][l]{$p'$} \\
                & m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2             &=& m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2\\
                & m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)            &=& m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)\\
\end{array}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are better solutions, but they need, e.g., some familiarity with `amsmath` package.

Comment: Hey,
this is also a good answer, however I prefer the easier solution above :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want the titles to be aligned with the leftmargin, here are two solutions, based on the `\shortintertext` command from `mathtools`and on the `flalign` environment. Each has two variants, according to whether the groups of `=` signs are aligned or not. The variants also differ in the placement of the equation numbers:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.2pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  \shortintertext{\bfseries Conservation of energy}
  E_\mathrm{kin}    & = E'_\mathrm{kin}                         \notag \\
  m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2       & = m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2}            \\
  m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)       & = m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)           \notag        \\
  m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1) & = m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)\notag        \\[2ex]
  \shortintertext{\bfseries Conservation of momentum}
  p     & = p'                               \notag        \\
  m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2     & = m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2                        \\
  m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)      & = m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)               \notag
\end{align}
\vspace{1cm}
\begin{flalign}
  & \textbf{Conservation \rlap{of energy}}
  & E_\mathrm{kin}      &= E'_\mathrm{kin}             &  &              \notag\\
  && m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2     &= m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \raisetag{1cm}   \\
  && m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)      &= m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)           \notag\\
  && m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)&= m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)\notag\\[2ex]
  & \textbf{Conservation \rlap{of momentum}}
  & p   &= p'                               \notag\\
  && m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2  &= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2                \\
  && m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)  &= m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)               \notag
\end{flalign}
\newpage
\begin{gather}
  \shortintertext{\bfseries Conservation of energy}
  \begin{aligned}
    E_\mathrm{kin}  & = E'_\mathrm{kin}                     \\
    m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2     & = m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2} \\
    m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)      & = m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)              \\
    m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1) & = m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)
  \end{aligned}\\[2ex]
  \shortintertext{\bfseries Conservation of momentum}
  \begin{aligned}
    p   & = p'                      \\
    m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2  & = m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2 \\
    m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1) & = m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)
  \end{aligned}
\end{gather}
\vspace{1cm}

\begin{flalign}
  & \textbf{Conservation of energy }
  &  & \begin{aligned}[t]
  E_\mathrm{kin}    &= E'_\mathrm{kin}                \\
  m_1 v_1^2 + m_2 v_2^2      &= m_1 {v'}_{1}^{2} + m_2 {v'}_{2}^{2}    \\
  m_1 (v_1^2 - {v'}_1^2)     &= m_2 ({v'}_2^2 - v_2^2)    \\
  m_1 (v_1 + {v'}_1) (v_1 - {v'}_1)&= m_2 ({v'}_2 + v_2) ({v'}_2 - v_2)
  \end{aligned}
  &  &
  \\[2ex]
  & \textbf{Conservation of  momentum}
  & &  \begin{aligned}[t]
  p     &= p'          \\
  m_1 v_1 + m_2 v_2   &= m_1 {v'}_1 + m_2 {v'}_2                \\
  m_1 (v_1 - {v'}_1)   &= m_2 ({v'}_2 - v_2)
  \end{aligned}
  &  &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]